# Finding values for a range of variables against the same constant

Tags: r

I am currently attempting to find the bias for a range of means previously calculated against the same constant. I have been using the code

`b_all<-bias(1,c(x2:x6))`

But its only returning the bias of the first variable x2. I'm sure there is a simple fix that I'm just not seeing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: what's x2-x6? Are these vectors? You'll need to explicitly list them (`c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6)`), or create a vector of vector names and provide that to the function.

Comment: Also - what package is `bias` from?

Comment: bias is in the "Metrics" package. Ok thanks. Very time consuming but if there is no other way don't have much of a choice

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without any data to verify, but this could work:

```
b_all <- sapply(2:6, function(i){bias(1,get(paste0("x", i)))})
```